# Search a file and open its folder vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using silver searcher in vim. A lot of times I want to search a file BUT open its folder (to see the other files that are there). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific workflow that you didn't disclose, `ag` is a red herring, here.

You can open the built-in file explorer in the parent directory of the current file with:

```
:Ex
```

You can also do:

```
:e %:h
```

because of the way Vim falls back to Netrw when you ask it to edit a directory.

See `:help :Explore` and its variants, as well as `:help filename-modifiers` for the `:h` bit.